# Laravel using send email using email host smtp.office365.com

Tags: laravel, email, smtp, office365

I got this error in laravel 6 right now,..
it is work in Gmail but in office365 i got this error.

```
 ". Authenticator XOAUTH2 returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [xxx.xxx.xx.outlook.com]
 "
```

this is my .env.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME="xxxxx@xxxxx.com"
MAIL_PASSWORD="xxxxxx"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="xxxxx@xxxxx.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="xxxx@xxxx.com"
```

Does anyone can solve this? :(

Comment: Do you have two step verification enabled on your office 365 ? if yes you need to disable it and try again

Comment: i dont know,... the credentials was given to our client,. the credentials are valid because i can login at office.com. i think it doesn't have 2 step verification because i can login directly,.  sorry for my english,.

Comment: I would suggest using a gmail account. outlook OR 365 have authorization issues which try to connect from a less secure app which is la-ravel it is considered.

Comment: it is office365 account sir